# Pooled stdev - why can't I replicate wikipedia? Numerical or understanding problem?

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics, rounding

I'm trying to replicate [example section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance#Example) from Wikipedia's article on pooled standard deviations. They say I should use following formula:

[image]

on the following table:

[image]

And get a result of:
[image]

But when I use the code below, I get a result of 2.7579928571428574, which can't be rounded to 2.764.

```
import numpy as np

def PooledStd(ns,stdevs):

    variances = stdevs**2
    numerator=0
    denominator=0
    for n,var in zip(ns,variances):
        numerator+=(n-1)*var
        denominator+=(n-1)
    result = numerator/denominator
    print(result)


n=np.array([3,4,2,5,5])

std=np.array([1,1.29,2.12,2.07,1.58])

PooledStd(n,std)
```

Am I misusing the for loop? Or is it issue with rounding in python? Or maybe I completely missed something?

Comment: You are using the rounded values of `s_i`. If you want to get the value they get, you would need to calculate the exact standard deviation for each set.

Comment: It's just a rounding issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the article uses the true values instead of the rounded numbers used in the table. You could replicate using your function by changing:

```
std = np.sqrt([1, 5/3, 4.5, 4.3, 2.5])
```

Note also it is good practice to use `numpy` functions to replace `for` loopse where possible to take advantage of the vectorization, which usually results in improved performance. The `PooledStd` function could be wrote as:

```
((ns - 1) * np.power(stdevs, 2)).sum() / (ns - 1).sum()
```